# How to close a window in QML/Javascript code (with C++ code involved)?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML window declared for example in MyWindow.qml:

```
Item {
    id: thisWindow
    width: 500
    height: 140
    ... sub-items that declare the UI of the window ...
```

And a C++ class that instantiates that QML:

```
class MyWindow : public QQuickView
...
MyWindow::MyWindow() {
    setSource(QUrl("qrc:/MyWindow.qml"));
    setFlags(Qt::WindowFlags(Qt::Popup));
}
```

How do I close that window from Javascript/QML code?
I can't call thisWindow.close(), because it's just an item type in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to export the `QQuickView` to the .qml with `setContextProperty()`:

```
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

// ...
{
    engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("view", this);
    setSource(QUrl("qrc:/MyWindow.qml"));
    setFlags(Qt::WindowFlags(Qt::Popup));
}
```

And then in QML you can use:

```
view.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need c++ to do that. You can do it with the [`window` attached property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#window-attached-prop) straight from QML.

```
//other imports
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {
    id: thisWindow
    width: 500
    height: 140
    //... sub-items that declare the UI of the window ...
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: Window.window.close()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Qt global object and follow the instruction here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#quit-method

Comment: The disadvantage of this method is that it will close the entire application with all the windows, not just the window that is desired